# Calling an assembly function from C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

One of my generated functions doesn't compute what it should and I am trying to debug it separately. I have the assembler for it and I try to call it from a stripped down C program. However, for some reason I end up getting segfaults in the function (so, calling the function seems to work, but execution fails). There might be something wrong with passing the arguments..

The functions signature is

```
void func(int, int, float*, float*, float*);
```

The function ignores the first two arguments and received 3 arrays of 32 floats each. It would add element-wise the latter two and store the result element-wise into the first array. However, it would do that in a kind of weird order (as opposed to streaming linearly through it, the reason for doing this is not in the scope of this SO question). That's what the `offset_arrays` are for in the assembler code.

I checked the x86 calling conventions (that's the architecture I am using) and the first six integer or pointer arguments are passed in registers RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, and R9.

Here' the function implementation:

```
    .text
    .globl  func
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   func,@function
func:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movabsq $offset_array1, %r9
    movabsq $offset_array, %r10
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:
    movq    (%r9,%rax), %r11
    movq    (%r10,%rax), %rdi
    movss   (%r8,%rdi,4), %xmm0
    addss   (%rcx,%rdi,4), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rdx,%r11,4)
    incq    %rsi
    addq    $8, %rax
    cmpq    $33, %rsi
    jb  .LBB0_1
    retq
.Ltmp0:
    .size   func, .Ltmp0-func
    .cfi_endproc

    .type   offset_array,@object
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
    .align  16
offset_array:
    .quad   0
    .quad   16
    .quad   1
    .quad   17
    .quad   2
    .quad   18
    .quad   3
    .quad   19
    .quad   4
    .quad   20
    .quad   5
    .quad   21
    .quad   6
    .quad   22
    .quad   7
    .quad   23
    .quad   8
    .quad   24
    .quad   9
    .quad   25
    .quad   10
    .quad   26
    .quad   11
    .quad   27
    .quad   12
    .quad   28
    .quad   13
    .quad   29
    .quad   14
    .quad   30
    .quad   15
    .quad   31
    .size   offset_array, 256

    .type   offset_array1,@object
    .align  16
offset_array1:
    .quad   0
    .quad   16
    .quad   1
    .quad   17
    .quad   2
    .quad   18
    .quad   3
    .quad   19
    .quad   4
    .quad   20
    .quad   5
    .quad   21
    .quad   6
    .quad   22
    .quad   7
    .quad   23
    .quad   8
    .quad   24
    .quad   9
    .quad   25
    .quad   10
    .quad   26
    .quad   11
    .quad   27
    .quad   12
    .quad   28
    .quad   13
    .quad   29
    .quad   14
    .quad   30
    .quad   15
    .quad   31
    .size   offset_array1, 256


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

I try to call the function from this C code:

```
float f0[32];
float f1[32];
float f2[32];

extern void func(int i0,int i1,float* dest,float* src0,float* src1);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  func(0,0,f0,f1,f2);
}
```

Compiling both and linking with

```
gcc -o f.o -c -g f.S
gcc -g -o test_f test_f.c f.o
```

and running though gdb results in

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
func () at f.S:17
17      movss   %xmm0, (%rdx,%r11,4)
```

So, this is obviously a write to memory, namely to the first array. Why would it segfault and how to call this function correctly (without changing the assembler code)?

Comment: Do you have the source code to the function you're debugging? That'd be a heck of a lot easier to work with than the assembly.

Comment: What are the register values after the crash? (just the ones from line 17)

Comment: SonOfSun and merridius, thanks for catching this. Changing the value to $32 works. Wow, then I will have to file a bug report to LLVM, since this assembler was generated from its x86-64 backend from IR that had the correct loop bounds :-(

Comment: how to debug asm: use gdb with `layout reg` and `layout asm`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more info and links.  In this case, since you already had gdb running on it, you could `x` (examine) the memory at the address referenced by `%rdx + r11 * 4`, and see that it was inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this line

```
cmpq    $33, %rsi
```

it should be

```
cmpq    $32, %rsi
```

you are accessing the junk in the memory after `.quad 31` and sticking that into r11 at `movq (%r9,%rax), %r11`

Comment: We found it almost together :)

Answer (score 2):

The size of the arrays is 32, but in the function the `%rsi` is incrementing from 0 to 33 with `jb` after it. It is wrong and access this part of static memory(not allocated) raieses a segmentation fault. It should be changed to 32. Tested in ubuntu.

```
func:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movabsq $offset_array1, %r9
    movabsq $offset_array, %r10
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:
    movq    (%r9,%rax), %r11
    movq    (%r10,%rax), %rdi
    movss   (%r8,%rdi,4), %xmm0
    addss   (%rcx,%rdi,4), %xmm0
    movss   %xmm0, (%rdx,%r11,4)
    incq    %rsi
    addq    $8, %rax
    cmpq    $32, %rsi
    jb  .LBB0_1
```